# jQuery syntax scrolling fade in and media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want this statement to fade a button in IF the two conditions are met, screen size over 767px and the scroll bar is past 600 and fade back out when you scroll back up to the top.

If the screen size is below 767px I want this jQuery to be null and not do anything.

Right now it is null below 767. But when it is above the button fades in but no longer fades our now I have added the second part of the if statement.

What's incorrect with my syntax?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600, $(window).width() >= 767) {
        $(".fixed-btn").fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $(".fixed-btn").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an AND operator between the 2 conditions so:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600 && $(window).width() >= 767) {
        $(".fixed-btn").fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $(".fixed-btn").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks for helping me on such a basic problem still learning the syntax.

Comment: && is very used not just in js.. Other operators are: || ---> or != ----> different

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `matchMedia()` for better performance:

```
// array so You can easily define more media queries in future
var media_queries = [
    window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 767px)')
];

function mq_0(mq){

    if(mq.matches){
        // .scroll_600 namespace so You can detach later only this event, in case of using scroll event in other scripts
        $(window).on('scroll.scroll_600', function(){

            // execute only once when .fixed-btn is not visible yet
            if($(this).scrollTop() > 600 && ! $(".fixed-btn").is(':visible')){
               $(".fixed-btn").fadeIn();
            }

        });
    }else{
        // detach event
        $(window).off('.scroll_600');
        $(".fixed-btn").fadeOut();
    }

}

// call on page load
mq_0(media_queries[0]);
media_queries[0].addListener(function(mq){
    mq_0(mq);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to read into this and look up on matchMedia(). Why is it a better performance increase? is it because you are setting the screen size as a variable which can be reused?

Comment: Main advantage of using `matchMedia()` is single call of the if statement. If media query is matched then the if statement is executed. Otherwise the else statement. In my example, when user access website with screen size > 767 then scroll event is never fired, and `fadeOut()` is called only once. Not everytime he change screen size or scroll. If he scale down screen size to 767px, scroll event will be attached to body only once and fired on page scroll of course.

Answer (score 0):

Button style: position:fixed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50 && $(window).width() >= 200) {
              console.log($(this).scrollTop() + ' ' + $(window).width());
               $('#mbtn').fadeIn();
      }
      else {
              $('#mbtn').fadeOut();
      }
  });

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="mbtn" style="display:none;position:fixed;">CLick me</button>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>
<br>
<p>My Text</p>



</body>
</html>
```